# detect scrolling in chrome extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm interested in detecting user scrolling using a chrome extension.

So I have tested some code on jsfiddle, right here: http://jsfiddle.net/hfxv7w6p/1/
and this seems to work. I'm successfully logging scrolling into console.

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
        console.log('Scroll up');
    }
    else {
        console.log('Scroll down');
    }
});
```

When I try to put this code into a chrome extension though:

I put that code into my background.js and set this as my manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Kittens",
  "description": "This extension demonstrates a 'browser action' with kittens.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery-2.1.1.min.js","background.js"]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs","bookmarks"
  ]
}
```

while i have jquery 2.1 min in the same folder as my workspace.

I can do a $(document).ready and have the console log a "ready", but why doesn't detecting scrolling work in this circumstance?

Is there a way to detect scrolling in the context of a chrome extension?

Comment: It is not appropriate to have code only in a Fiddle in a Stack Overflow question. By all means keep the link, but also include relevant code here. Also note the new "snippet" functionality to embed small examples here.

Comment: Okay there. now can you please help me?

Comment: Okay, show us the `popup.html` too. Which file do you put the scrolling code in?

Comment: Alright I figured out. Because the page is the thing that's detecting the scroll, the code needs to be injected into the page that is loaded each time.

Comment: @adsfdsafdsa could you please share a more robust Answer?